# Django graphen Create Mution fireing Error

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

These are my schmema

```
import graphene
from graphene import relay, ObjectType, Mutation
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField

from cookbook.models import Ingredient



class IngredientType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient

class IngredientCreate(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        note = graphene.String(required=True)
        id = graphene.ID()

    ingredient = graphene.Field(IngredientType)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, name, note, id):
        ingredient = IngredientType.objects.create(
            name = name,
            note = note
        )
        return IngredientCreate(ingredient=ingredient)



class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_ingredient = IngredientCreate.Field()
```

and this is my models.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField()
```

I am trying to create Ingredient from graphql django gui but fires me syntax error

```
{
  createIngredient(
    name: 'rice cooking',
    note: 'a simple note',
  )
}
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me please what is the possible reasone that i cant create a record?

Answer (score 1):

In graphql, you need to use double quotes for string values, not single quotes. So, if you do this, everything should work:

```
{
  createIngredient(
    name: "rice cooking",
    note: "a simple note",
  )
}
```